# Passing a text file of astrometry to a HTML form

Tags: java, html

I am trying to download an astronomical catalogue from the website http://tgss.ncra.tifr.res.in/tgss_cb.html

However, I have can only download parts of the catalogue (out to 4 degrees). The site requires me to input positions and a search radius. The system works by calling information in a cgi-bin that I do not have permission to access.

What I have is a text file that contains different positions that will allow me to download the entire catalogue (essentially moving a circle around the survey area).

I want to pass this text file to HTML form with no manual input.

Is there a way to loop around this website so that my co-ordinates are inputed, submitted and the file is downloaded, and then moves onto the next position, with no manual input?

Sorry if this is simple but I have limited HTML/Java experience.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easyly send a HTTP-Request to the Webserver through java. in the best case it is a get-parameter (www.xy.com/test.php?this=is&theGet=parameter) to set and you are ready to go.

so you generate a HTTP-Request to the webserver, passing your parameters by generating the link-adress according to your wanted position:

```
www.space-map-stuff.com?dontKnow=65626879&whatToPass=651681
```

Comment: Thanks. That kind of worked but I had to change "Post" to "get" to get the full url that is being passed. After that it was a simple bash for loop using wget.

Comment: yay, i am glad, it helped you! =)